# How can you recurisvely return non-concatable values?

Tags: java, return, concatenation, return-value

So we all know how this recursive faculty function works:

```
public static int fac(int number) {
    return (number > 1) ? number * fac(number - 1) : number;
}
```

If you call this with 5 as argument it will evaluate to:

```
return 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1
```

So far, so good. But what if the values I want to return are not able to be concatenated? For example if I want to return some Lists:

```
public static List<Integer> getSubarraysOf(List<Integer> array) {
    if (array.size() <= 1) {
        return array;
    }
    return array + getSubarraysOf(array.subList(1,array.size() - 1));
}
```

Of course this doesn't work! The only way I can imagine this to work is by referencing a **global variable** (being a List containing Lists), to which the resulting Lists are added, or to introduce the resulting List as a **parameter**. Both solutions smell and I wonder if anyone out there has a more clever solution than me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for solution like this

```
public static void main(String [] args)
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 1; i < 6; ++i) list.add(i);
    System.out.println("1### " + list);
    System.out.println("2### " + getSubArraysOf(list));
}

private static List<Integer> getSubArraysOf(List<Integer> array) {

    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); ++i) {
        result.addAll(array.subList(0, array.size() - i));
    }
    return result;
}
```

with following results

```
1### [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
2### [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1]
```

or maybe like that

```
public static void main(String [] args)
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(5);
    System.out.println("1### " + list);
    System.out.println("2### " + getSubArraysOf(list));
}

private static List<Integer> getSubArraysOf(List<Integer> array) {

    int lastItem = array.get(array.size() - 1);
    if (lastItem == 1) return array;
    array.add(--lastItem);
    return getSubArraysOf(array);
}
```

with result

```
1### [5]
2### [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Comment: I think what I want is just not possible, returning multiple objects. I would have wanted to have a List containing all the subarrays, so I can process each subarray individually.

Comment: I think so, only with external List<List<Integer>>